# How can I print the calling program/module inside a method in Perl?

Tags: perl, trace

I have written a Perl API and it is used by many programs across teams. I want to track all programs calling my API method. I want to have something like the below

```
 debug("The calling method is ",  $XXXX);
```

How to get $XXXX ?

Answer (score 11):

[perldoc -f caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).

```
print "The calling function is", (caller 1)[3], "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Also see the functions in the [`Carp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Carp) module, which wrap the `caller` function and can serve as a sort of warn function with caller information.

```
use Carp qw(carp cluck);

carp "This function was called from ";  # caller info will be appended to output

cluck "The full stack trace up to this point is ";
```

Comment: Thanks mobrule. This is more than what I expected. Cool, thanks!